# How to check whether file in perforce workspace is in sync with given label or not?

Tags: perforce

I am looking for command which will retrieve the result whether file inside a perforce work space is synced with given label. I searched on net and found commands like:

```
p4 sync -n @labelname
p4 files @labelname
p4 labels
```

But none of them is serving my purpose.

So, please help me out and suggest how I can check weather file in Perforce work space is in sync with given label or not.

Answer (score 1):

<s>`p4 sync -n @labelname`</s> is close, except you haven't specified the file path. Please use `p4 sync -n [PATH]@labelname`, e.g. `p4 sync -n ...@labelname`.

If you're synced, the output will be `...@labelname - file(s) up-to-date.`.

Comment: It's legal to omit the file path; it will default to "//...". Note that "..." is slightly (but importantly) different than "//..."; without the slashes, the path is relative to the current directory. But if it's a specific file you're looking for, you could specify the file name instead of the "...".